My texture has uncolored edges in my mesh
Could be a problem of my model, Im new at this. When exporting (This case onto Roblox) that uncolored edges are there. I started with a plane mesh and I made a Smart UV Project to color It. In Blender I can only see It from a far distance. In Roblox Its just like an uncolored edge in the texture




Can you take a look at the image texture in the Image Editor and zoom in to see what is going on? That almost looks like cavity masking was turned on when the image was being painted. Also, in the 3d view go to Edit Mode and select a face close to the issue and press the period key on the numpad and it should zoom to the face.
